# Update jQuery datatable options dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have created on jQuery datatable with few options as given bellow.

```
var _myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData": arrayList,
            "aoColumns":columnArr,
            "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']]
        });
```

After creating that I need to add **fnRowCallback** method to that table using the variable **_myTable.**
Is there any way to add my fnRowCallback to an existing table? I don't want to recreate that data table with fnRowCallback option. I want to re use **_myTable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will work for datatable version 1.9. It has changed a lot in 1.10, may not work with this version. Thanks.

Try this:

```
var oSettings = _myTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.aoRowCallback.push( {
    "fn": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
       $(nRow).on('dblclick', function() { alert('sdagdsa'); });
    },
});
_myTable.fnDraw();
```

For 1.10, try something like this:

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable(); 

var oldoptions = oTable.fnSettings(); 

var newoptions = $.extend(oldoptions, { 
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) { 
    console.warn("working"); 
} 
}) 

oTable.fnDestroy(); 

$('#table').dataTable(newoptions);
```

Comment: Getting this error - Uncaught TypeError: _myTable.fnSettings is not a function

Comment: fnSettings is a legacy API method that I was using. As you are using the modern $().DataTable() initialisation. Use settings(). I'm updating answer.

Comment: var oSettings = myTable.settings();
oSettings.fnRowCallback  = function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ){
 $(nRow).on('dblclick', function() {
  alert('sdagdsa');
 });
};
This code works fine without error. But while doubl click the row I didn't get the alert. Actually it seems fnRowCallback is not applied to that dataTable.

Comment: I checked with recent update. Getting following error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: what is your datatable version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135250/discussion-between-prasath-and-shi).

Comment: DataTables 1.10.12